# How do I shutdown JBoss AS 7 server?

Tags: shutdown, jboss7.x

I recently updated from `jboss-as.7.1.0.CR1b` to `jboss-as.7.1.0.Final` and want to shutdown running instance from the console. In previous versions the command

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-admin.sh --connect command=:shutdown
```

was available, but I do not see `jboss-admin.sh` in the bin directory or other shell scripts for shutting down the server.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

For some reason the JBoss team decided to reorganize the scripts between minor revision upgrades. In any case, jboss-cli.sh is the replacement for jboss-admin.sh (they are for all intents and purposes the exact same script). So your new shutdown command is:

```
 ./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
```

Comment: The script has been renamed in a way that makes it more accurately reflect the purpose of the script. The word "admin" can be confusing, where AS7 offers both a Management CLI and a Management Console.

Comment: Hey @ddri. I don't have a problem with the new name, so much as the timing of the change. In the end its not ***that*** big of a deal.

Comment: Agreed. As long as we all get there in the end :)

Comment: @Perception Can you also include the shutdown command on other OS like windows? Thanks

Comment: add --controller=<your machine IP, eg 10.0.2.12>:9999 between shell and --connect if your instance is not bound to localhost

Comment: Awesome, I did it like so, because i have multiple cluster instances on localhost:  SET NOPAUSE=true&&./jboss-cli.bat --controller=127.0.0.1:10399 --connect command=:shutdown

Comment: @Prakash K Its the same as on linux, but remove the .sh extension:

Answer (score 23):

For standalone mode,

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
```

For domain mode, hostname should be specified like this:

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect  /host=master:shutdown
```

'master' is the default hostname. The server hostname could be found in $JBOSS_HOME/domain/configuration/host.xml

If you have set security realm then use:

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=<host>:<port> --user=<username> --password=<password> /host=master:shutdown
```

Answer (score 6):

If your server has the controller listening in a different URL than localhost:

```
${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=<host>:<port> command=:shutdown
```

Only for your information. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In Windows ......jboss-eap-6.1\bin\jboss-cli.bat 
Double click or run by cmd prompt.

Answer (score -1):

```
 ./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
```

when I use this command in standalone mode it off , but when I 'm in an ssh connection must exit and enter again and then run this command

Answer (score -1):

I just want to contribute the answer for Jboss 5.x server, because the question is relevant to JBoss shutdown.

For Windows, proper syntax is mentioned below:

```
${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/shutdown.bat -s jnp://applicationHostedEnvironment:portNumber -S
```

For example:
If the application is hosted on local machine with the port 1099 then use:

```
${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/shutdown.bat -s jnp://localhost:1099 -S
```

For Linux, 
Syntax:

```
${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/shutdown.sh -s jnp://applicationHostedEnvironment:portNumber -S<br>
```

For example:
If the application is hosted on local machine with the port 1099 then use:

```
${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/shutdown.sh -s jnp://localhost:1099 -S
```