# How do I shutdown JBoss AS 7.1.0 from the command line?

Tags: ubuntu, jboss7.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I shutdown JBoss AS 7 server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327233/how-do-i-shutdown-jboss-as-7-server)

I installed jboss-7.1.0 and linked it to my jboss symbolic link to upgrade it from jboss-7.0.2 on an Ubuntu server. Unfortunately my init.d script no longer works since it seems 7.1.0 does not ship with jboss-admin.sh scripts.

What replaces jboss-admin.sh found in 7.0.2 in JBoss AS 7.1.0?

Comment: I believe you can have a look at this thread for the answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327233/how-do-i-shutdown-jbossas-7-server

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
jboss-cli.sh  --connect command=:shutdown
```

Comment: The jboss-admin.sh has been renamed jboss-cli.sh to better clarify the purpose of the script.

Comment: if your instance is not bound to localhost, add --controller=< your machin ip, eg.10.x.x.x>:9999 to the command

Answer (score 0):

```
jboss-cli.sh --connect  /host=*:shutdown
```

Comment: When running this command, I get this message "JBAS014739: No handler for shutdown at address"

Comment: with standalone you can simply use

jboss-cli.sh --connect :shutdown