# how to shutdown Jboss server 7.10 final using command for windows version

Tags: jboss7.x

Am using windows Jboss 7.10 final. For shutdown the jboss linux server commands are available, but I cannot able to find the commands for windows. Ctrl+C will terminate the process, but **i require shutdown commands for windows**. I have tried below mentioned commands but not working.

```
./jboss-cli.bat --connect controller=<IP>:<PORT> command=:shutdown
```

Hope below mentioned linux command will not work in windows version.

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
```

I need to shutdown the server using IP and port level, because i am running more than one containers in the same server.

Help me to find the right one. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I shutdown JBoss AS 7 server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327233/how-do-i-shutdown-jboss-as-7-server)

Comment: I have to down the server using IP and PORT. May be this will down all the containers ?

Comment: "I need to down the particular container. Like 10.80.xx.xxx IP and 4447 port. Can you please provide the solution for this. I don't want to down all the containers, because i am running 4 containers. " - please add relevant information like this into the question itself. Your setup of containers matters to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you stop JBoss depends on how it was started. This task covers stopping an instance that was started interactively, stopping an instance that was started by a service, and stopping an instance that was forked into the background by a script.

This task does not address stopping a server or server group in a Managed Domain. For those scenarios, see Section 2.8.3, “Stop a Server Using the Management Console”

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Stop_a_Server_Using_the_Management_Console1.html

Procedure 2.1. Task:

- **Stop an instance which was started interactively from a command prompt.**

Press Ctrl-C in the terminal where JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6 is running.

- Stop an instance which was started as an operating system service.

Depending on your operating system, use one of the following procedures.

1. Red Hat Enterprise Linux

For Red Hat Enterprise Linux, if you have written a service script, use its stop facility. This needs to be written into the script. Then you can use service scriptname stop, where scriptname is the name of your script.

2. Microsoft Windows Server

In Microsoft Windows, use the net service command, or stop the service from the Services applet in the Control Panel.

- **Stop an instance which is running in the background (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)**

  1. Locate the instance from the process list. One option is to run the command ps aux |grep "[j]ava -server". This returns one result for each JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6 instance that is running on the local machine.
  2. Send the process the TERM signal, by running kill process_ID, where process_ID is the number in the second field of the ps aux command above.

Answer (score -1):

Go to **bin** **folder** in the `JBoss` location

E.g. (In my PC) - Windows 8, 8.1 and 10

```
D:\Servers\jboss-4.2.3.GA\bin
```

Press **Shift** key in the keyboard and **right click**

Select Open Command Window Here

Then type, `shutdown.bat -S` and enter

It will take some to down the server and then you are good to go.